# How to change the src value of object/embed tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, src

```
<object id="aa" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="650" height="400">
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
<param name="movie" value="test.swf">
<embed src="test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="400"  bgcolor="#000000">
</object>
```

i want to change the value of src inside embed tag

```
  src="test.swf" to  src="newlink.swf"
```

tried something like this but not work.

```
            $("#aa").attr('src' 'new link');
```

Comment: The selector should be `$("#aa")` not `$("aa")`
`$("aa")` is TAG NAME selector.

Comment: I don't believe you can change the URL of an SWF. You must remove the old `object`, and build a new one and append the new node to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You need to use [**ID Selector ("#id")**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)</s>

```
 $("#aa embed").attr('src', 'new link');
```

OR

```
 $("#aa").find('embed').attr('src', 'new link');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Muq6M/1/)

### EDIT

```
var aa =  $("#aa").clone();
aa.find('embed').attr('src', 'http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/fireworks.swf')
$("#aa").replaceWith(aa);
alert( $("#aa").find('embed').attr('src'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Muq6M/3/)

Comment: @mwweb, in demo I have also modified value of `<param name="movie" value="test.swf">`, do take care of that when you implement it